# Summing and grouping according to city and payment type with laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have three different tables: cities, payment_types and payments. I want to create summary report for the payments.

cities table:

[image: cities table]

And then payments type table:

[image: payment type]

And payments table:

[image: payments]

What I want to get is (I want to create this summary)

[image: summary]

so, according to summary city doesn't repeat and grouped by payment_types.

How can I create this query with Eloquent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create proper relations for your eloquent models, like this:

City.php

```
class City extends Model {

    public function payments() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Payment');
    }

}
```

PaymentType.php

```
class PaymentType extends Model {

    public function payments() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Payment');
    }

}
```

Payment.php

```
class Payment extends Model {

    public function city() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
    }

    public function payment_type() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\PaymentType');
    }

    public function scopeFromCity($query, $cityId) {
        return $query->where('city_id', $cityId);
    }

}
```

After this initial setup, you are ready to go to create your report:

```
// Get all cities from DB
$cities = \App\City::all();

// Loop through each city
$cities->each(function($city) {
    // Print city id and name
    echo "City ID {$city->id}\n";
    echo "City Name {$city->name}\n";

    // Now we will fetch all unique payment types for this city
    // and we will loop through each of them
    // calculating the total of payments done
    // for this payment type and city_id
    $paymentTypes = \App\PaymentType::whereIn('id', \App\Payment::where('city_id', $city->id)->lists('payment_type_id'));
    $paymentTypes->distinct()->get()->each(
        function($paymentType) use ($city) {
            echo "Payment type {$paymentType->type}\n";
            $total = $paymentType->payments()->fromCity($city->id)->sum('payment');
            echo "Total {$total}\n";
    });
});
```

You can find more information about Eloquent from the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent), Taylor has explained everything very well with examples.

Comment: shaddy thanks for answer, its works but i want to name they in html, is this enough for this? because naming is inside this code, i mean i have to send object to the blade then use foreach there

Comment: actually i want to get it object to send blade

Comment: You can just put the variables in an array during the loop and then just pass the array to the template :)

Comment: shaddy, by the way, second part doesnt work ($city->payment_types..) payment_types and cities doesnt have any relational key in table

Comment: Yes they do not, but I explained why this works at the bottom of my answer. It is achieved with `hasManyThrough` relation. In the link I gave you there are more explanations about this. Did you run the code and it did not work for you or you are just assuming it would not work?

Comment: i tried the code. first part works but second parts  ($city->payment_types() ... ) returns empty

Comment: in second part, even "Payment type" title doesnt seem.

Comment: @yigitozmen Ah sorry, it seems like I have switched the place of the kyes here `return $this->hasManyThrough('App\PaymentType', 'App\Payment', 'payment_type_id', 'city_id');` can you try changing this line to be like this? At the same time I am going to test the code on my local machine just give me 5 minutes :)

Comment: now there is an error, it searches city id in payment type, but there is no city id in payment type table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78865/discussion-between-yigitozmen-and-shaddy).